# Salesforce App Cloud vs Force.com PaaS - what's the difference?

Tags: force.com

Salesforce recently released the Salesforce App Cloud: http://www.salesforce.com/uk/platform/overview/ & https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2015/09/salesforce-app-cloud.html.

I am a bit confused and unclear as to what the Salesforce App Cloud exactly is and how it differs to the Force.com PaaS offering.

As per https://www.salesforce.com/paas/overview/, "**The App Cloud brings together the power of Force.com and Heroku into one family of services to give you the most complete PaaS tools available**".

From that, I am assuming that the Salesforce App Cloud gives one the ability to develop apps aimed at customers super quickly in a wide range of programming languages (Heroku), whilst getting the data from customer interactions integrated closely with the Force.com platform. BTW - this link helped me understand a bit more about the nuances of Heroku and the Force.com platform: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Force-com-and-Heroku

Is this assumption correct, or is there something else about the Salesforce App Cloud product offering that is really compelling vs the Force.com PaaS?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a mix between heroku and force.com.  It will offer the flexibility of heroku and the cloud security of force.com.  Also, it brings Private Spaces (only available in heroku) to force.com.   Private spaces allow a mix of on-prem control and cloud based security.

Also, it brings the backends of Heroku and Salesforce on to the same back end. Heroku is on AWS while Force.com is on the salesforce infrastructure.

Force.com is a high-control environment, used by business people who are not necessarily code jockeys to create applications that fit their compliance needs. Heroku is the high-productivity type used by developers who want to hand wire applications from scratch to get exactly what they want.  App cloud offers both of these.

So yes, your assumption is correct but there are other features that make this melding a useful offering.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer :) Can you elaborate a bit further please on: "Also, it brings the backends of Heroku and Salesforce on to the same back end"? What back end does Salesforce App Cloud sit on? Thanks

Comment: App cloud sits on the same backend as Force.com (salesforce servers).  Currently Heroku sits on AWS EC2 servers.  So by combining them, in app cloud, it moves Heroku from Amazon (AWS) to the salesforce backend.